# вернуть and вернуться

Tags: суффиксы

Both seem to be perfective and mean "to return".

I saw more verbs that have -ться counter parts.

What is the difference ?
What meaning does "-ться“ carry ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Вернуть* is to return as in give something back. *Вернуться* is to return as in come back.

*-ся* (which becomes *-сь* after a vowel, except in adjectival participles) is simply the reflexive particle. *Вернуться* is literally "to return oneself".

*-ться* is, grammatically, just the sum of its parts (infinitive *-ть* + reflexive *-ся*); phonetically, though, it's notable for its irregular non-palatalised pronunciation, e.g. *напиться* rhymes perfectly with *пицца*. Moreover, *-ться* is identical in pronunciation to the third-person present *-тся*, resulting in perhaps the most commonplace of spelling mistakes made by Russians, a sort of cultural equivalent of "your"/"you're".

Comment: an oldie but goldie: *"Здесь хорошо спиться." "-тся." "-ться."*

Answer (score 3):

Consider "I return" (or "I'll be back") = "Я вернусь" vs "Return it to sender" = "Вернуть отправителю".

"-ся" is the reflexive particle much like one in German/Italian/Spanish etc. You may treat "вернуться" as "return oneself" although hardly anyone says so in English.

Answer (score 2):

Compare:

"Я должен вернуть долг. Скоро заканчивается его срок."

"Я хочу вернуть книгу."

"Она хотела вернуть любовь."

and:

"Я должен вернуться домой. Забыл ключи от гаража."

"Мы можем вернуться к первому вопросу из списка."

"Они собрались вернуться на корабль."